# selenium query: javascript equivalent find.element (by.xclass)

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

I have to find in an html page a id tag which is embedded in a class tag.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Content warning']/p").get_attribute("id")
```

[image]

I made it worked with selenium, the instruction is:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Content warning']/p").get_attribute("id"))
```

Nonetheless, despite the fact it works perfectly, it is a bit slow, and I would like to try a javascript code injected directly into the page (with a code injector)

Therefore, I am looking for the equivalent of the selenium instruction in **javascript**.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is your paternity, and I thank you very much. I answered to you directly in the previous message. As I do not have enough "reputation" on the platform, I cannot formally provide official feedback.  thanks again.

Comment: sorry I did not know. I just accepted it, it should be ok. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In javascript that would be:

```
driver.execute_script('''
  return document.querySelector('div[class="Content warning"] > p').id
''')
```

Answer (score 0):

While @pguardiario seems correct, you could do this as well in Python to execute the JS code (and can use Selenium `get_attibute`)

```
content_warning = driver.execute_script('''
  return document.querySelector('div[class="Content warning"] > p')
''')
content_warning.get_attribute('id')
```